# how to multiply axis values by a factor of 100

Tags: matplotlib

Both x and y scale values in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHeLN.png) should be multiplied by 100.So that x-axis and y-axis values should be 0 2500 5000 7500 10000 12500 15000 17500 20000
My plot  remains unchanged even after multiplying the data by that factor.

Input data https://www.file.io/GAYM/download/dDB51UAJdAG5

My code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt("input.txt")
plt.imshow(100*data,cmap='jet', interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying the data doesn't help because your data only includes the pixel values but not the coordinates.

A quick and dirty hack is to modify the [tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html):

```
def formatter(x, pos):
    del pos
    return str(x*100)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

A more proper way is to use the `extent` keyword argument as explained in [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html) but I don't have time right now to tailor that to turn that into an answer to your question. Maybe someone else (or you) does.